# How to stop when i click on Ok in javascript error?

Tags: apex, javascript

I have One custom button and developed one web service class and invoked in javascript of that custom button.  Based condition i populated one error. I need to make it Not to run after i click on Ok of error popup. If i press OK rest of code should not excecute.

Here is my Custom button code:

[image]

Here is popup when i click on custom button:

[image]

If i click on Ok then should be at same page, but rest code is excecuting:

[image]

How to stop after i click ok in javascript?

Comment: You could return null from your method if no records found, then write the execution portion of the javascript to only run when result != null

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is confusing. The alert will always appear and can only be closed by clicking its OK button.

Instead do you only want to show the alert when "No Opportunity Found" is returned? In that case use:

```
var result = sforce ...
if (result == 'No Opportunity Found') {
    alert('Result is ' + result);
} else {
    // Copy rest of code in here
}
```

(If you want to give the user the choice of proceeding or not use [confirm](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) not alert.)